# Polar coordinates integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Compute the following integrals  over $R$

$f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ over the area $R$ where:

$f(x, y) = x$
 and
$R$ is given by $0 ≤ r ≤ \cos θ$ and $f(x, y) = x$.

I understand polar coordinates is probably the most suitable.
We can convert $f$ into  $r^2\cos(\theta) \,dr\,d\theta$.

The bounds for the $r$ variable is $0$ to $\cos(\theta)$.
I'm not too sure how to get the bounds for the theta variable. 
My first guess is that it's from $0$ to $2\pi$ (simply because whenever I did integration with polar coordinates, it was always integrating a whole circle, so from $0$ to $2\pi$. I'm not too sure what to do in this case).

But in the solutions, they are integrating theta from $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I'm having a hard time understanding why.

Comment: So the problem is to integrate $f$ over $R$? As it stands, I'm not sure what $R$ is -- I assume it's a set of points, like $R = \{(r, \theta) \mid 0 \le r \le \cos(\theta), ? \le \theta \le ?\}$, but the bounds on $\theta$ could be anything, as you've realized. Is there any more info in the problem?

Comment: Sorry. I've added a bit more to the body. R is simply give as 0 ≤ r ≤ cos θ and the function f(x,y) is given as x. The question has the integral set up as the double integral over the area R, and the integrand as f(x,y) dx dy

Comment: I still don't understand, unfortunately. Do you see the problem I'm talking about? To specify a 2D region, you need to put bounds on both coordinates.

Comment: According to the solutions: R is the region: disk of radius 1/2 centered at (1/2, 0).  However, this information isn't given in the problem itself.  The final answer is pi/8.

Comment: Ah, it's a polar plot!

Comment: Was there enough information given in the problem? Can you explain it to me?.

Comment: Are you familiar with polar plots, where $r$ is a function of $\theta$? This (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r+%3D+cos%28theta%29) but filled in, is your region (because the region is all $0 < r < \cos(\theta)$).

Comment: I'm not. But from the picture that you linked, I can tell now why the bounds are what they are. But how can you tell from the problem that R is this "polar plot"? without the additional information "R is the region: disk of radius 1/2 centered at (1/2, 0)." that wasn't given in the actual problem.

Comment: Posting an answer that will hopefully explain. It is indeed possible to tell, I was just confused.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime $r$ is given as a function of $\theta$ (or bounded by a function of $\theta$) you have a [polar plot](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolarPlot.html). You can plot a lot of shapes with simple equations relating $r$ and $\theta$. If you're doing problems like this, but haven't seen polar plots before, ask your professor; this isn't something you should "just know".

Here's the region (disk of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ sitting half a unit along the $x$-axis. This is not strictly necessary in order to do the integration, but I *always* find it helpful.

[image: disk to be integrated over]

Our bounds are $0 \le r \le \cos(\theta)$, obviously, and also $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$, since $\theta$ needs to swing from the bottom to the top to trace out the region.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\iint_R f(x, y)\,dx\,dy &= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\cos(\theta)} r^2\cos(\theta)\,dr\,d\theta\\
&= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos(\theta)\left(\frac{r^3}{3} \bigg|_{0}^{\cos(\theta)}\right) \,d\theta\\
&= \frac{1}{3} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^4(\theta)
\end{aligned}
$$

Here I appeal to Wolfram again, to integrate $\cos^4(\theta)$ on those bounds. It gives $\frac{3\pi}{8}$, so we have:

$$
\frac{\pi}{8}
$$